# Strange lucky wheel on my Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

There is a strange app that appears on top of my Whatsapp (Android) on the right side, if I click on it, an lucky wheel appears on the center of the screen, as the attached image. What a heck is this, some kind of virus? I was unable to find similar image on google. Also, it is not listed on my apps. Where can I find it?

[image]

Comment: It does seem to be some sort of malware. I did some Google searches and there were many articles about a "Lucky Wheel" in Whatsapp, but the picture didn't quite look the same. Try downloading the Avast anti-virus for Android and see what happens. [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity&hl=en) is a link so you download the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the source, it is an ad from my Keyboard app, [Go Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard).

It's a good keyboard app, but those ads forced me to give it a low score.